# How do you connect multiple guitars to a single output?

Tags: electric-guitar

I'm planning to start teaching Electric guitar. I want to be able to connect at least 4 Guitars into a speaker or amp. How can I do it ?

Thanks.

Comment: It would probably be easier and cheaper to buy four little amps like Roland micro cubes than it would be to buy a mixer with four instrument inputs and then some kind of amp or powered speaker for the mixer outputs. Just get four amps. Anything more complicated will cost more and be difficult to use.

Comment: Also, you'll probably eat up the headroom pretty quick with four people playing into it. I get some pretty nasty sounds (in a bad way) from just one guitar with a loop pedal especially when hitting the same frequencies pretty hard.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done fairly easily with one amp, and a 4 input mixer. However, there's the fiddle of balancing the guitars, and all the leads going to the same place, and not hearing separated sounds. As Todd says, 4 separate amps will do a better job - each in its own place, so each can be heard and controlled separately. Yes, it will mean four mains wires but each player will be happier with his own sound. Buying pre-loved won't cost much different. If some of the amps have two inputs, that will future proof things too, when you may want more than four inputs. You did mean inputs, I guess?

Answer (score 1):

For teaching, no-one needs to 'rock out', so a single amp and speaker should do the job.  You can buy a 4-input mixer very cheaply.  The inputs won't be optimised for electric guitar, but sound will come out!  Try.  These little mixers are so cheap, you can treat it as an experiment.

Comment: I agree – though this is really no good for any performance / recording situation, it should be perfectly ok for teaching.